# R: function that matches names of two data sets

Tags: r, function

I have two datasets:

```
Names =
code meaning
A    Blue
B    Red
C    Green
```

```
Df =
Observation
A
B
B 
C
```

I want to create a function in r that matches the `Names$meaning` of the `Names` data into Observtion so:

```
Df =
Blue
Red
Red
Green
```

So far I have tried:

```
modifyNameFunction <- function(x) {
  if (x = Df$Observation) {
  return(Names$meaning)
  }
}
```

Recall that it has to be in `function` format.

Comment: Take a look at `?merge`, or maybe `?match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `match` like below

```
Df$Observation <- with(
  Names,
  meaning[match(Df$Observation, code)]
)
```

which gives

```
> Df
  Observation
1        Blue
2         Red
3         Red
4       Green
```

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thanks for the answer. Is there a possibility to have it in a function format with the commands ```if``` and ```return```?

Comment: @Economist_Ayahuasca Do you want `modifyNameFunction <- function(x) {
  Names$meaning[x==Df$Observation]
}`